# usage of "and" in stead of comma

Tags: punctuation, commas

> 1. Perishable  foodstuffs, quick  frozen  fruit,  vegetables  and  meat  are  kept  in  refrigerated self-service  cabinets.
> 2. Perishable  foodstuffs  **and** quick  frozen  fruit,  vegetables  and  meat  are  kept  in  refrigerated self-service  cabinets.

I found theses two sentences on google.
Are there difference in meaning in sentence 2, using "and" in stead of "comma" in the phrase"perishable foodstuff and quick frozen fruit"?

Answer (score 1):

In the first sentence, it's possible, but unlikely, that "quick frozen" could be interpreted to apply only to "fruit."

By separating the two categories of items as is done in the second sentence, it causes the reader/listener to lean more toward applying "quick frozen" to all items in the list.

If only the fruit is quick frozen and you want no ambiguity, do this:

> Perishable foodstuffs, vegetables, meat, and quick frozen fruit are kept in refrigerated self-service cabinets.